# Integral of dyadic double dot product on a unit sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to reconstruct an analysis from fluid dynamics textbook and I got all terms with the exception of one:

$$
\oint_S\! (\mathbf{e} : (\mathbf{n} \, \mathbf{n}))\, \mathbf{n}\, \mathbf{n}\, dA, 
$$
where $\mathbf{e}$ is a 2nd order symmetric tensor with $e_{ii} = 0$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are normals. The integration is over a unit sphere.

I believe the result should be 0. The non-matching indices in the contraction will form odd functions so vanish under integral whereas matching indices will vanish due do $e_{ii}=0$ condition. But I'd like a confirmation or some neater proof of this. I don't really have geometric intuition about double dot products of dyadics so I am afraid my operational transformations may be misguided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $e$ is constant, move it outside of the integral
$$J = e:\oint n\,n\,n\,n\,dA$$
Then use the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084949/surface-integral-of-normal-components-summations-on-a-sphere) to write it as
$$\eqalign{
J &= \frac{4\pi R^2}{15}\,(e:{\mathbb Y}) \cr
 &= \frac{4\pi R^2}{15}\,(e+e^T+e\operatorname{tr}(e)) \cr
 &= \frac{4\pi R^2}{15}\,(2e) \cr
 &= \frac{8\pi R^2}{15}\,e \cr
}$$

Comment: The OP probably meant to say that the tensor $e$ is skew-symmetric instead of symmetric, in which case $J=0$